# Send mail using mpack without attachment

Tags: shell

How can I send mail without attachment?

```
mpack -s 'SUBJECT' message.txt $To
```

This shows the message.txt file sometimes as a body while receiving mail and sometimes it shows file attachment while receiving the same mail. I need to show always text in this file as a mail body.